# Does realloc and calloc call malloc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, malloc

This is probably an easy question but I couldn't find an answer. Is malloc internally called within realloc and within calloc? Since I am somehow counting the malloc calls, it is interesting for me. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to look at your compiler's implementation.

Comment: Are you compiling in C or C++?

Comment: Many compilers simplify their code by having one memory allocation function.  `calloc` and `realloc` and maybe `malloc` usually will call the same memory allocator.  HOWEVER, there is nothing in the standard that says that `calloc` and `realloc` must call `malloc`.  The compilers are free to implement these functions as they see fit as long as their implementation meets the specifications in the language standard.

Answer (score 6):

You should not try to depend on system, library or compiler dependent mechanisms. Even if you know realloc calls malloc on one system/compiler/library, you cannot be certain that it will be handled the same way on other systems.

The question at this point would be, what you are trying to achieve. If you need to track memory usage, there are better ways in C++, for example installing a global replacement for operators new and delete. In some versions of Linux you can also add hooks to malloc (never used this feature though). On other systems you can use other mechanisms to achieve what you need more safely.

Comment: actually, i am implementing hooks for malloc etc. to track dynamical memory usage. Do you know any better ways to do that?

Comment: well, and if realloc calls malloc as well, I would need to consider this in my program.

Comment: Don't write your own tool to track dynamic memory usage.  Use tools that are already written and tested.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do it the answer would be: Don't do it and use the tools that are much better than anything you would be able to write or use a new handler or write your own memory handler and force everyone to use that one. The question still remains: What is it you are trying to achieve (i.e. Why do you need memory tracking), not how you want to achieve it.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews & LiKao: I am writing a program that does tracks dynamic memory (well, it actually only want the accurate value of maximum used dynamic memory) and with the results decides which further steps to take (it should automatically monitor the performance).

Comment: You could use libproc for this, it should be able to figure out the actual memory used by the program in real time (including memory not used directly but internally). This is much more reliable than using other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working on Linux you are probably using glibc.  You can look at the [glibc malloc source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=malloc;h=399edb0dcd0f0f8f3b7de505cb241fb9688816b3;hb=HEAD) and see that it calls something called __malloc_hook from functions like calloc.  This is a [documented feature you can use](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) to intercept and count allocations.  You can get other useful statistics from [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc).  But see if there's an existing tool which achieves what you want first.  Memory management debugging and statistics are a common requirement!

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple test program which calls realloc and calloc and feed it to callgrind (one of tools from Valgrind). It will show call graph so you can check what functions are called by malloc and calloc on your libc implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know from the languages standards. C99 says nothing about the functions calling each other, or not.

C++ only says that `malloc` can not call `new`, but has no other such restrictions on either function.